# Why does this particular JavaScript code work this way?

Tags: javascript

```
var my_obj = Object.create({}, {
    getFoo: {
        value: function() {
            return this.foo;
        }
    }
});
my_obj.foo = 1;

alert(my_obj.getFoo());
```

Why is `getFoo` the function instead of `value`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) takes [property descriptors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) as input :

> `propertiesObject`
>
> If specified and not `undefined`, an object whose enumerable own properties (that is, those properties defined upon itself and not enumerable properties along its prototype chain) specify property descriptors to be added to the newly-created object, with the corresponding property names.

and `value` means:

> `value`
> The value associated with the property. (data descriptors only). Defaults to `undefined`.

But as `getFoo` implies, it might be better to define it as *accessor property*:

```
var my_obj = Object.create({}, {
    foo: {
        get: function(){ 
            return this._foo; },
        set: function(newValue){ 
            this._foo = newValue; 
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually.. its just because you set value to equal a function.

If you were trying to run that function anonymously, you have to include that after the declaration. Observe:

```
x = { y : function(){return 2;}}

x.y
function (){return 2;}

x = {y : function(){return 2;}()}

x.y
2
```

Note the trailing () after the function declaration.

Sorry for the 1 line code, came right from a javascript console.